# How to play audio over speakers rather than the much weaker ear speakers?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-audio

I'm learning core audio. For some reason the sound of the processing graph only plays through the weak "ear speakers" (when you hold device to your ear) but not over the regular speakers of the iPhone.

This is the code which sets up the audio session but I can't see where it configures the audio route:

```
- (void) setupAudioSession {

    AVAudioSession *mySession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

    // Specify that this object is the delegate of the audio session, so that
    //    this object's endInterruption method will be invoked when needed.
    [mySession setDelegate: self];

    // Assign the Playback category to the audio session.
    NSError *audioSessionError = nil;
    [mySession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord//AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                     error: &audioSessionError];

    if (audioSessionError != nil) {

        NSLog (@"Error setting audio session category.");
        return;
    }

    // Request the desired hardware sample rate.
    self.graphSampleRate = 44100.0;    // Hertz

    [mySession setPreferredHardwareSampleRate: graphSampleRate
                                        error: &audioSessionError];

    if (audioSessionError != nil) {

        NSLog (@"Error setting preferred hardware sample rate.");
        return;
    }

    // Activate the audio session
    [mySession setActive: YES
                   error: &audioSessionError];

    if (audioSessionError != nil) {

        NSLog (@"Error activating audio session during initial setup.");
        return;
    }

    // Obtain the actual hardware sample rate and store it for later use in the audio processing graph.
    self.graphSampleRate = [mySession currentHardwareSampleRate];

    // Register the audio route change listener callback function with the audio session.
    AudioSessionAddPropertyListener (
        kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange,
        audioRouteChangeListenerCallback,
        self
    );
}
```

At which point in core audio do you say "play over speakers" when playing sounds with audio units?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `setCategory` `withOption:`

```
[mySession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:&audioSessionError];
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Turns out it is something to do with the "play and record" category. Just need to redirect the audio output.

```
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;

AudioSessionSetProperty (
    kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
    sizeof (audioRouteOverride),
    &audioRouteOverride
);
```

Source:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW35

Comment: Tried this but it did not work, user523234 solution is what worked for me.