# Can I send sound to the speakers when headphones are connected?

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio

I'm running a roleplaying game that involves demonic forces, so to make it a little more fun, I wrote a tiny program with [EZAudio](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio) that takes the microphone input and plays it back with the pitch lowered by 400%. Overlayed with my actual voice, it sounds pretty evil (when I can focus enough to avoid the [speech jamming](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/427116/how-to-build-a-speech-jamming-gun/) effect).

The problem is that I don't have a dedicated microphone, and the feedback is pretty intense when I run it with the internal microphone and the internal speakers. I do, however, have earbuds with a microphone and a 4-ring jack, which my MacBook pro recognizes. Now, the problem is that when I use it, the sound goes to the earbuds, which defeats the whole purpose.

Mac OS X supports multiple audio output devices. However, as far as I can tell, my 2010 MacBook Pro exposes just one, which dynamically routes sound to either the internal speakers when no headphones are connected, or to the headphones when they are. `EZAudioDevice`'s `outputDevices` returns just one entry in both cases.

Is there a way I can divert the sound to my computer's internal speakers even when headphones are connected?

Comment: Unless the close-voter knows for sure that there is no programmatic way to direct sound to the speakers, I'm not sure why this is being called a general hardware/software problem.

Answer (score -2):

In core audio for iOS, [it is not possible as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175082/force-iphone-to-output-through-the-speaker-while-recording-from-headphone-mic).  You are running Mac os and I would assume that the behavior would be the same.
The best option is to use a mic not associated with the headphones.  Use a usb preamp with a mic.

Comment: Are you sure about that? [This more recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14835857/251153) says that you can.